# How can I replace the entire HTML of a page, or its body content, via an AJAX call's success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, replaceall, replacewith

I need to replace the entire HTML of a page, or its body content (rather than append more html to the existing content).

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297254/why-is-my-rest-method-not-being-called-by-this-jquery) showed me how to return data, but adding it to "body" doesn't *quite* work. This is the jQuery I have now:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName : "QuadrantData", routeValues : new { httpRoute = true , unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "2016-08-20", enddate = "2016-08-27"  })',
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                cache: false,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: false
                },
                success: function (returneddata) {
                    $("body").remove;
                    $("body").append($(returneddata));
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
                }
            }); // ajax
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        }); // button click
    }); // ready
</script>
```

...So you can see I'm trying to first remove the html in the body, and then append the returned data to the body.

This REST method returns the html I want:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name = "QuadrantData")] 
public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
{
    _unit = unit;
    _beginDate = begdate;
    _endDate = enddate;
    string beginningHtml = GetBeginningHTML();
    string top10ItemsPurchasedHtml = GetTop10ItemsPurchasedHTML();
    string pricingExceptionsHtml = GetPricingExceptionsHTML();
    string forecastedSpendHtml = GetForecastedSpendHTML();
    string deliveryPerformanceHtml = GetDeliveryPerformanceHTML();
    string endingHtml = GetEndingHTML();
    String HtmlToDisplay = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",
        beginningHtml,
        top10ItemsPurchasedHtml,
        pricingExceptionsHtml,
        forecastedSpendHtml,
        deliveryPerformanceHtml,
        endingHtml);

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            HtmlToDisplay,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "text/html"
        )
    };
}
```

...but it appends the returned html rather than replacing it - the original body html is intact, and the returned html appears below it at the bottom of the page.

How can I replace, rather than append, this html? I tried replacewith and replaceall, but these didn't work for me.

Comment: I'd use [the .html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function on the body instead of  `.remove` and `.append`

Comment: `$("body").remove;` what?

Comment: Do remove() instead of remove

Comment: I expect a follow up question asking why javascript in the ajaxed in page doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433890/replace-entire-page-with-contents-of-an-ajax-loaded-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`remove()` will remove the body element (instead of just clearing it out). You can use this to match what you are trying to do

```
$("body").empty();  
$("body").append($(returneddata));
```

but it would be better to use

```
$("body").html(returneddata);
```

You also may want to look into the [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function which will place the html into the element(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you sending content type text/html your code should work as it is.

Try using Jquery.parseHTML function like this

```
$("body").append($.parseHTML( returneddata )));
```

Also you have a mistake in line

```
$("body").remove; 
//it should be empty() since remove() remove all the content including body it self
$("body").empty();
```

Link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using `$.get()` and `.html()`. Your .remove call would not have worked because of a syntax error (missing parentheses) and because `.remove()` would have *removed* the body altogether, so that you could not have appended anything to it afterwards. You would have had to do something like

```
$(document).append($('<body>').append(returneddata));
```

in order to re-create the BODY node and appending data to it.

Also, you should put the cursor reset code in the .always handler, though, otherwise it will be set *and reset* before the .get or .ajax call has a chance of executing.

In general,

```
console.log('this is executed first');
$.get('...', function(){
    console.log('this should be executed third... sooner or later');
});
console.log('this is almost certainly executed second');
```

So your code could be:

```
$('#btnGetData').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css({ cursor: 'wait'});
    $.get(
          '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName : "QuadrantData", routeValues : new { httpRoute = true , unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "2016-08-20", enddate = "2016-08-27"  })'
            )
    .done(function(data) {
       // Replace 
       $('body').html(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
       // Always plan for errors. Murphy rules.
       alert("error");
    })
    .always(function(){
        $('body').css({ cursor: 'pointer'});
    });
})
```

This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf385mb6/) of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already use `jquery`, you don't really need to use it for this. In order to replace the html of the body element with html stored in the variable `newHTMLstring`, put this in your callback function:

```
document.body.innerHTML = newHTMLstring;
```

If you want to clear the html of the body element first, just set `.innerHTML` to an empty string:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

This vanilla js is faster and works in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set your ajax result to body as below:

$("body").html(ajaxresult);

Still it is not working then make sure jquery is loaded properly and also write your script on document ready,

$(document).ready(function(){

// Your AJAX call request

});